# How can I have different background colors in the same animation?

Tags: css, animation, colors, background, animated

On my nav bar I have 4 different buttons and I want each one of them to have a different color when I hover them.

[Here is a demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/34hsjLc7/2/)

And here is the code used for the animation:

```
.hvr-underline {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
transform: translateZ(0);
box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
position: relative;
}

.hvr-underline:before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
   left: 50%;
   right: 50%;
   bottom: 0;
   background: #2098d1;
   height: 4px;
   -webkit-transition-property: left, right;
   transition-property: left, right;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
   transition-duration: 0.3s;
   -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
   transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.hvr-underline:hover:before, .hvr-underline:focus:before, .hvr-underline:active:before {
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

Instead of all four buttons having the same blue color I'd like each one of them to have different colors in the animation.

Comment: you could use nth-child to update background-color http://jsfiddle.net/34hsjLc7/3/  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add another class name to your existing class names something like

```
<li class="hvr-underline blue"><a href="#">Button1</a></li>
<li class="hvr-underline green"><a href="#">Button2</a></li>
<li class="hvr-underline red"><a href="#">Button3</a></li>
<li class="hvr-underline yellow"><a href="#">Button4</a></li>
```

In CSS you can add another def something like

```
.hvr-underline.blue:before {
    background:blue;
}

.hvr-underline.green:before {
    background:green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/34hsjLc7/4/

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I don't know why but I already tried that before and it didn't work and after your answer I still couldn't do it, I just copied the exact and it worked somehow. I still don't know if it was just me derping.